# SSAS 2014, relation to time dimension using YYYYMM field. Best practice?

Tags: ssas, cube

In the process of creating a new cube for my client, I encountered a problem I'm not sure hot to deal with.
I have a table that doesn't have a DateTime field; instead it has a varchar field which contains year and month in YYYYMM format. I need to create a relation to my Time dimension using that field; and proceed with creating Year-Quarter_Month hierarchy.

First thing I did was creating a new named calculation in Time table from the date field to match the YYYYMM format. Now, I understand that the relation can't be created because it would break the referential integrity.

My idea is to create a new Time table/dimension and delete all records except the first day of the month, create a YYYYMM named calculation and then I would be able to create a relation between my table and that new Time table. But, is this the right approach and what downsides I can expect?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate time dimension...when connecting the new fact table to the existing time dimension (in the dimension usage tab) you can set the YYYYMM attribute as the "granularity attribute"...SSAS will handle the rest :-)

[image]

Also, if the format is YYYYMM (ie. 201504 for april 2015) then you might consider making it an integer (instead of a varchar) to save some space in your fact table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new calculated column in that table to add the first day of the month:

convert(date, YYYYMMfield*1000+01)

and then link it with your key in your time dimension.

This way, your YYYY-QQ-MM hierarchy levels work as intended, if the user is going deeper and wants to see monthly values on a daily basis, he will find all values for that month added to the first day.